# export table containing pictures (BLOB) from ms access to mysql

Tags: mysql, ms-access, blob, ole

i have a database table in **MS-ACCESS format** (MDB) containing structure as

```
Form_No   Int
Picture   OLE OBJECT
```

when i import this table in **MySQL** using navicat, then the PICTURE field converts to **BLOB** and the field has no images(IMAGES ARE LOST). what to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OLE objects are tricky beasts - it is not exactly trivial to convert them into pictures.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90908/Saving-OLE-Object-as-Image-Datatype-in-SQL) is an example of C# program (about 5KB) that can convert OLE object to few supported formats (JPEG, BMP, PDF, WORD).

You should be able to adapt it to your needs. I would think it will be easier to create new BLOB picture column in MS Access table first, convert it to real JPEG (not OLE!) using C#, and only then export it to MySQL.